# Splitting of data in two clusters using kmeans matlab

Tags: matlab, k-means

I have a large dataset in which i want to divide into two clusters using kmeans algorithm in matlab.Here my problem is that those two clusters should contain the data present in the dataset.How can I do that in matlab?

```
For eg:
1 2 3
4 5 6
6 3 5
1 1 2
```

....
in the output I should get in this format:

```
cluster1:
...
1 2 3
1 1 2
cluster 2
4 5 6 
6 3 5
```

Comment: yes I know that kmeans function is already there.it will divide into 2 clusters.but i want to get the datapoints present in the clusters.How to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   idx=kmeans(dataset,k)
```

//dataset-the dataset for your kmeans
//k=number of clusters
then to know what is assigned into the clusters
try this

```
    cluster1data=dataset(idx==1,:)
```